# How do I get min and max of one number that is constantly changing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this number that is constantly changing, for example lets say it goes through 50 to -50 I want to save to another float when it gets to it's lowest point in this case -50 and I want it to save to another float when it gets to the highest point 50.

Comment: What's the issue, what have you tried? Do you know the maximum and minimum ahead of time or are you trying to find a point where the line changes from ascending to descending or vice-versa? Or is the issue simply how to compare floats where equality testing isn't a good idea?

Comment: The wording is a bit unclear. Do you want to be tracking the min and max throughout the lifetime of this constantly changing number?

Comment: So I have an object orbiting another object, I want to track the point where the the orbiting object is closest to the object it is orbiting and the same for the furthest point.

Comment: If you had a list of numbers, could you get the min and max then? Your issue works the same way

Answer (score 1):

Declare and keep two variables on your class, one should track and hold the minimum value, the other - the maximum.